# Linker not able to find the template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have following scenario ..

(sorry for the long (& detailed code presentation), but not sure how to explain this problem otherwise)

--- misc.cpp ---

```
template <typename T>
const T& mymax(const T &a, const T &b) {
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

--- misc.h ---

```
#ifndef __MISC_H__
#define __MISC_H__

template <typename T>
const T& mymax(const T &a, const T &b);

#endif /* __MISC_H__ */
```

--- test.cpp ---

```
include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "misc.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *arg[]) {
    A turtle {"Turtle", 70}, hbird{"Humming bird", 47};
    
    turtle.show();
    hbird.show();
    A animal = mymax<A>(turtle, hbird);
    animal.show();

    return 0;
}
```

--- A.h ---

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__
#include <iostream> // for std::ostream
class A {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const A&);
    private:
        char *str;
        int i;
    public:
        A(const char *, int);   // Overloaded constuctor
        A();                    // No-args constructor
        ~A();                   // destructor 
        A(const A&);            // copy constructor
        A(A&&);                 // move constructor
        A& operator=(const A&); // copy assignment
        A& operator=(A&&);      // move assignment
        bool operator>(const A&) const;
        void setint(int i=0);
        void show();            // display
};

#endif /* __A_H__ */
```

A implements operator> like this --

--- A.cpp ---

```
bool A::operator>(const A& rhs) const {
    if (i > rhs.i)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Now if I build it, it is giving me below error:

```
 make
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -c A.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -c misc.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -c test.cpp
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall A.o misc.o test.o -o test
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: in function `main':
/home/onkar/cc/learncpp/stl/test.cpp:23: undefined reference to `A const& mymax<A>(A const&, A const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:5: test] Error 1
```

Not sure what's wrong.

Can anyone, please help me figure this out.

Comment: Side note: `__MISC_H__` violates [C++ naming rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). This is an error that rarely bites you, but when it does it's a complete mind<expletive deleted> because the results rarely make any sense. Best to religiously adhere to the rule.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. This is really nice learning & insightful.